# Cannot assign to 'stockItems' because it is a read-only property. TS2540

Tags: reactjs, properties, immutability

Trying to run a React project in VisualStudio and I'm getting the following error on running on:

localhost:44373

```
    C:/Users/---------/ClientApp/src/App.tsx(87,20):
    Cannot assign to 'stockItems' because it is a read-only property.  TS2540

    85 | 
    86 |         // set the state
  > 87 |         this.state.stockItems = data;
       |                    ^
    88 |         this.state.loading = false;
    89 |     }
    90 |
```

Comment: Can you provide the type interface you defined for the state of App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to set the state variable directly, you should be using React's `setState` function: `this.setState({ stockItems: data })`

Answer (score -1):

```
// set the state
//this.state.stockItems = data;
//this.state.loading = false;
this.setState({
    stockItems: data
});
this.setState({
    loading: false
});
```

Comment: Fyi you can combine that into one statement, as React handles merging of state: `this.setState({ stockItems: data, loading: false })`